# Centering line lenght from small to bigger with CSS

Tags: css, text

How can I center text in CSS so that the output text is styled from smaller to bigger lines and centered? Example output (without the dashes) :
              ----------          DO YOU HAVE 
                 ------        AN IDEA AND NEED
                   HELP IN ORDER TO PURSUE IT?

Thank you!

Comment: `text-align:center`?

Comment: So a line break after 3 words, then 4 words, then 5 words etc? And @TemaniAfif that's not fully what he's asking.

Comment: Try this: <h1 style="text-align:center;">DO YOU HAVE<br/> AN IDEA AND NEED<br/> HELP IN ORDER TO PURSUE IT?</h1> Check out for more details @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @Bram based on the actual state of the question, it's *unclear* what they are asking. (there is 6 words in the 3rd line by the way)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree on the fact that it's not the clearest question and understand your point, but he's asking `from smaller to bigger lines and centered`.

Comment: PLEASE post a [mcve] show us what HTML and CSS you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* This will break the text after each span */
span::before {content: '\A'; white-space: pre;}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <span>DO YOU HAVE</span><span>AN IDEA AND NEED</span><span>HELP IN ORDER TO PURSUE IT?</span>  
</div>
```